# Grails, display blank if value is 0.0

Tags: grails, gsp

I want fields that contains a numeric value of 0.0 to be displayed as blank.
How can I do that in a grails view?

Heres the gsp code:

```
<g:each in="${od.plannedVolumes}" status="j" var="pv">
       <td id="pv_center">${pv.volume}</td>
</g:each>
```

pv.volume is declared in the domain as a Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of groovy truth you could output a non breaking space if zeroed.

```
<td id="pv_center">${pv.volume ?: '&nbsp'}</td>
```

Comment: Feel a bit stupid but what does " non breaking space" actually mean? For the moment I use just a reference to the data in html. And I just want the field in the view to show blank. The data in the domain is numeric so it must still be 0.0 so the view must take care of it. I could probably use <g:if> to fix it but thought that there is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space can you show exactly what you're using now

Comment: I've read that wiki now and of course in this case, where no input is done it doesn't care just that the fields space is blank and not disturb anything else in the view. Yes, you can look in my question I added the part of the gsp that contain this field. Shall I include the whole GSP? In fact, it's just a template.

Comment: Ok, that worked except that I couldn't use '&nbsp' as it took it literally, instead an empty string ('') was sufficient. Maybe it matters because I use the "render plugin" to print a pdf-file in this case. Thank's a lot!